# dmg file of 'LTspice for Mac' won't start-up

Tags: mac, installation, quicklook

I have been working on 'LTspice for Mac' on my Mac-mini. From the version of "Build Oct  3 2016, 14:49:11 US Pacific," trials of updating the tool started to keep failing.

Yesterday, I upgraded macOS from High Sierra to Mohave (10.14.4), and tried to update it from the App's menu, and to make a clean install after deleting the existing App (LTspice).  The problem remained unchanged; the installer won't start up, and I found it left the log (/var/log/system.log) like:

> Apr 17 06:13:00 falcon com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.quicklook[714]): Endpoint h
> as been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_che
> ck_in(): com.apple.quicklook

After some searches, found several reports of installation troubles whose error message include com.apple.quicklook, but I cannot figure out what to do on my Mac.

Could someone advise me of how to solve the issue?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Chris.  Analog Devices Co. has updated the LTspice to XVII, and it is now working fine for me.  I am sorry for the delayed notice.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, once you click on the .dmg file, there isn't a pop-up. However you must go into "locations" in your computer, then click into LT Spice Installation and drag LTSpice into the Applications folder. Hope that helps!